# i want to get all meta tags of any page also the repated meta tags

Tags: php, javascript, tags, meta

i am using this code to alert all meta tag in the page. for e.g. http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/2769 in this many meta array are used i want to extract all the meta tag on another page.please help me . thanks in advance

```
  window.onload = function(){
    var metaData = document.getElementsByTagName('meta')

for(var i=0;i<metaData.length;i++)
{
alert(metaData[i].name);
alert(metaData[i].content);

// talk to your db here for individual entries of meta using name and content
// properties

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're trying to access the meta tags in a remote page. You'll want to use PHP for that, since Javascript won't be able to access the details in that page.

Luckily, there's [`get_meta_tags`](http://php.net/get_meta_tags) function. You can do something like:

```
$url = 'http://shodhganga.inflibnet.ac.in/handle/10603/2769';
$tags = get_meta_tags($url);
print_r($tags);
```

Example:

```
echo $tags['generator'].'<br>';
echo $tags['dcterms_spatial'].'<br>';
echo $tags['dc_creator'];
```

Output:

```
DSpace 1.8.2
Physical education
Balasubramanian, K
```

And then, you can pass the values to Javascript and use it however you like.

Hope this helps!

Comment: thanks @Amal Murali, but it is not displaying repeated meta tags like Dc.Subject

Answer (score -2):

in php have get_meta_tags. Using this you can get all meta tags & its attributes.

```
$tags = get_meta_tags('page_url');
echo $tags['author'];      
echo $tags['keywords'];     
echo $tags['description'];  
echo $tags['geo_position'];
```

Comment: its not working on any arrayed meta tag like DC.subject, DC.relation